# Right triangle in a square...

Tags: geometry, triangles

On side $BC$ of the triangle $ABCD$ is point $E$, and on the side $CD$ is point $F$. If $AF=10cm$, $AE=8cm$ and $EF=6cm$ calculate a side of the square. The farthest I got is that $AEF$ is a right triangle. How do I continue?

Comment: $ABE$, $ADF$ and $BEC$ are also right triangles. Let $x$ cm be the side of the square and try to find an equation about $x$ by consider area.

Comment: I'm still not sure how.

Comment: A triangle has three vertices.

Comment: @Christian, perhaps *A* and *B* are coincident. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\angle EFC =\theta$. Then it follows that $\angle AEB =\theta$ as well. Further, say the side of the square is $x=AB=BC=CD=AD$.

From $\triangle AEB$, we have$$x=8\sin \theta \\ BE = 8\cos \theta$$

From $\triangle EFC$, $$EC=6\sin \theta$$

$$\therefore BE +EC = x = 8\cos \theta + 6\sin \theta \\ \implies 8\cos \theta +6\sin \theta = 8\sin \theta \\ \implies \sin \theta=4\cos \theta 
\\ \implies \frac{\sin \theta}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2 \theta}}=4 \\ \implies \sin \theta =\frac{4}{\sqrt{17}}$$

and so $$\boxed{x=\frac{32}{\sqrt{17}}}$$